# Linux Installation problems

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, usb, installation

I bought an 8GB USB 2.0 stick just to install Linux.

I have Ubuntu iso file, I use 'UUI' and make my usb bootable then when I start it doesn't go to installation screen. Changing boot order didn't work. I even changed UEFI to Legacy mode but then it would say no bootable drive detected.

I have an old laptop by Acer. It has Win10 at the moment.

Please help...

Comment: How is your USB formatted?  Also, try to use [UNetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io/).

Comment: I don't think the old Acer bios worked, but if you can force the default to UEFI and update to latest BIOS you might get there.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick May be this link will help you. Currently which OS you are using, is it a new system or there is any Os installed in it? Which USB stick you are using i.e. its 2.0 or 3.0. Some new USB sticks doesn't allow to boot. Same case happened with me recently i was trying the same way you did for ubuntu. In my case it was Windows 7, so i run setup.exe file from the USB and rest it will do automatically.

Comment: USB 2.0 and have win 10

Comment: Try this. create a new USB boot using power iso or UnetBootin. Turn off secure boot and fast boot options. restart your windows 10 by holding shift key. Go to Troubleshoot --> Advanced Options --> Startup Settings and click on restart. I hope you will get list of options try from that. hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

The fastboot mode needs to be disabled from your current OS(Windows 10) This the probably the main cause preventing you from booting into your USB stick.
[How to disable fast startup in Windows 10?](https://windowsable.com/how-to-enable-or-disable-fast-startup-in-windows-10/)